# arabic characters insertion php mysql XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: php, mysql, xml, encoding, quotes

Below is the contents I am trying to insert into `textbox` (with `maxlength=50`) and records saved in mysql database.

`(2) إنشاء طلب توقيع شهادة من المفاتيح ماك الخاص بك وحفظها على القرص

(3) تحميل لتوقيع طلب الشهادة. سيرت توقيع طلب إلى بوابة برنامج

(4) انتظر لتوليد سيرت (حوالي 1 دقيقة). تحميل الشهادة (وكالة الأنباء الجزائرية _ مطور _ الهوية. السرطان) ​​من بوابة برنامج (إذا كنت في حاجة لتجديد هذه سيرت، وهي تحت معرف التطبيق الذي قمت بإنشائه في الخطوة 1، واختيار العمل تكوين)

(5) حافظ (أو تسميتها إذا كنت تفضل ذلك) هذه الملفات 2 (الخطوات 2 و 4) في مكان آمن. قد تحتاج لشهادة توقيع طلب توقيع طلب سيرت ملف لطلب سيرت جديدة للالتطبيق الجديد في المستقبل أو تجديد سيرت من العمر عندما انتهت صلاحيتها.`

When it is saved it shows like:

`(2) إنشاء طلب توقيع شهادة من �`

And returns an error with xml parsing, I am using `htmlspecialchars` function before returning to xml - but that doesn't work here.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>`

I am adding `utf-8` as well with xml output

Any Idea, how to overcome this.

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Comment: similar question of writing XML may help.
see 
[formatting string for xml..][1]


[XML support for arabic][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467213/formatting-string-for-xml-attribute-in-php
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574306/php-xml-creator-doesnt-support-persian-arabic-encoding-utf-8

Comment: // reduce the long string to store in database and remove xml parsing error with unknown characters
 
 function tokenTruncate($string, $your_desired_width) {
  $parts = preg_split('/([\s\n\r]+)/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  $parts_count = count($parts);
  
  $length = 0;
  $last_part = 0;
  for (; $last_part < $parts_count; ++$last_part) {
   $length += strlen($parts[$last_part]);
   if ($length > $your_desired_width) { break; }
  }
  
  return implode(array_slice($parts, 0, $last_part));
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read ,write and sort Arabic text in mysql database using php correctly, make sure that:

1- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

2- MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

3- your database and table collations are set to: utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

SOURCE: [MySQL-FORUMS](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,209072,209072).